# PHP file execution

Tags: php, shell

Hey, I'm trying to use PHP to execute a shell command which will run remotely run a server on my box. Here is my PHP Code:

```
if ($key == "test") { echo "<font color='green'>Key is valid. Server satrted.</font>";
   $start = system('cd /root/st/; ls;');
}
```

The problem is, the ls command runs from the same directory as the web server, which returns all of the files from /var/www/html instead of /root/st/. I have also tried the chdir command to no avail. Anyone know how you would get the directory to change so that the command could be run from a specified directory? Thanks.

Comment: What are the permissions on that directory, /root/sl ?

Comment: why not `system('ls /root/st/');` ?

Comment: ls was just an example, I'm trying to execute an actual file (./zserv -IWAD DOOM2.WAD -port 13051)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the user that PHP is running as (eg, the user invoking the CLI script) have permission to read the directory?  If you're going into `/root/` but aren't `root`, you'd need to either add `cd` to sudoers for the current user, or choose another directory.

Edit: note that adding `cd` to sudoers is not even remotely okay for anything other than a local, you-only script. :)

Comment: Do you know any workarounds in that case? Why would using cd not be okay?

Comment: @Ivan, I assume you've already been lectured on how utterly awful of an idea a PHP script running as root is?

Comment: Yes I know, haha. This is just a test and nobody else will see it for the moment.

Comment: No, using the `cd` command itself is fine - adding it to sudoers so that other users could execute it as root would not be. :)  Also, since this is running inside a web server, are you having basedir restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I would approach this.

1: use proper unix commands, and see if they work. IE:

```
if ($key == "test") { echo "<font color='green'>Key is valid. Server satrted.</font>";
    $start = system('ls /root/st/');
}
```

2: Make it run a script on the system, that can go outside the webserver's chroot.

```
if ($key == "test") { echo "<font color='green'>Key is valid. Server satrted.</font>";
    $start = system('server.sh');
}
```

and server.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /root/st
ls
```

Comment: Couldn't users access the bash script in that case?

Comment: Yes, they could, if you don't properly secure the system. But, if they are able to modify that script, your box is probably owned anyways.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a [`chdir()`](http://php.net/chdir) function. Not sure if it applies to exec/system calls, but worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Store the location in a variable, say `$loc = '/root/st'` and then do `ls $loc` in your code. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the directory the script is running in (or more precisely the current working directory of the user running the script), but that `cd /root/st/` will fail on any reasonable configured UNIX/Linux system. `/root` is usually owned by `root` and can't be accessed by any other user.

Using you snippet this will silently fail because you unconditionally chained the `cd` and the `ls` commands with a semicolon instead of `&&`.

Comment: What if apache is run off of the root user?

Comment: It usually isn't. You have to explicitly set the `User` directive in your `httpd.conf` to use that user and some distributions prevent running Apache httpd with root privileges at all.